# Fill Down until Last Empty Row or Next Filled Cell

Tags: vba, excel, copy, autofill

I know how to code in order to fill down a column, but I have a few conditions that I can't find out how to implement.

I want to fill down until the last row (that contains any value at all) or the next cell within the column that contains information.

The data looks like this

```
a        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
b        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
c        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
d        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
e        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

So as you can see, the code needs to recognize how to stop at b (and not copy over it) when copying down the column. Also the code needs to stop at the last row with values in it when dragging down e.

I've been trying to figure it out to no avail, please help!!!

Previous code:

```
Yes I do have some code, but it is slow and I would like to figure out something more efficient.
'Sub CopyDown()
    Sheets("RAW").Range("A1").Select
    For i = 1 To 100
        ActiveCell.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            ActiveCell.Paste
        End If
    Next i
End Sub'
```

Comment: Do you have an example of code that you wrote that's not working?

Comment: Yes, i linked the code into the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is simple, if your example dataset is used (filling down the existing values to the blanks in Column A.)

```
    Sub MacroFillAreas()

    For Each area In Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If area.Cells.Row <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
            area.Cells = Range(area.Address).Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next area
```

(Code Modified)

```
   End Sub
```

Comment: Checking on this now. This is new to me!

Comment: So the only problem is finding a way to stop it at the last row that contains values. Otherwise I LOVE how this works. It is very fast. Still it copies well past the last row

Comment: It does not go beyond the last row when run on the dataset I created by copying your sample data above. Anyway, I think I can modify the code so it does not go beyond the last row. Will take a few minutes...

Comment: Strange that it works on my sample data and not the actual data... There is nearly no difference besides that the "1-10" here is not as clean on the actual set. In my set there are empty cells dispersed

Comment: Just tested and it works perfectly. This is a bit advanced for me at this point, but it does what it is supposed to. Ill have to study up on it :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without Code its hard to say, but assuming you are doing a loop, then all you need to do is check the cell

```
Sub filldown()

Dim X, Y As Long
Dim MaxX, MaxY As Long

MaxX = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
MaxY = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For X = 1 To MaxX
    For Y = 1 To MaxY
        If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(X, Y)) = True Then
            ''Do something
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I do believe this is okay, but I dont see how this would understand that it has reached the last column. A big issue is that every column to the right of column 1 where we are doing this has the possibility of at one point being a null cell, or empty, so if i simply check that a cell has a value as we go down, it might not hit anything (if that makes sense)

Comment: @CodingNovice Oh i was under the impression it was just for column A ... so do you want this to run on the entire UsedRange?

Comment: Not exactly. It is just column A, but the issue is that the code needs to stop copying once it passes row 50 or row 100. Whichever row is the last one being used! tbur above gave a good code, but it is beyond me for now